# How do I "cookie-cut" my world texture only using my existing object?

Tags: transparency, compositing-nodes

[image]I have a scene with a world texture, light and 3D object.

To create a desired effect, I need to render the silhouette of my 3D object as a "cookie-cut" of my world texture. (Please see picture below)

I am trying to find out what is the compositor node set up to do something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you render your object with a transparent background, yuor render will have an alpha output in which the object will be white and the background black. In the compositor you can use this output in the input of a "Set Alpha" node which carries the background image you want (a render of the background sky  or directly the image of the sky).

[image]

Comment: Would it be too much to ask if you could show me a screenshot of the final node set up? I'll be able to follow it.

Comment: I added an image. In this workflow the rendered mesh was saved as PNG RGBA, then charged in the compositor as image.

Comment: Thank you! This worked beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

Replace anything you use in your Reindeer material with a *Holdout* shader:

[image]

Now in the top-right corner, rename your view layer to *reindeer*, then create a new view layer, rename it to *background*, and in that new view layer, disable the collection containing the reindeer:

[image]

Now go to the *Compositing* tab, and enable ✅ *Use Nodes* on the top bar. Duplicate the  *Render Layers* node and switch the original node's View Layer to *background*. Now connect the duplicate node's *alpha* to the output (*Composite*) node's alpha, but through *Math* node in *Subtract* mode in order to reverse the alpha:

[image]

Make sure in the render settings, *transparent* option **is not** enabled:

[image]

Now render the image and save it.

[image]

Comment: Okay this is ALMOST working! However, I want to make sure this is a world node setup your cutting out. I want to cut my environment out in that shape.

Comment: @Shorty305 I'm not sure what you mean by world, or environment. In the answer, I used HDRI as environment texture for the world node setup. https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=ballroom

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to achieve this. If I understand you correctly, you have an HDRI or any other image as *Environment Texture* in the world background, and you want your object to be the mask for this environment.

In the *Render Settings* simply enable *Film > Transparent* so that the environment texture is invisible for the camera. On your masking object use a *Refraction BSDF* with pure white color, Roughness set to 0 and IOR also at 0. Now the background is shown in the silhouette of the object, which already shows if you look at the rendered view in the 3D Viewport.

[image: refracted background]